# Can the sum of already-contracted future debt be deducted from zakat due now?

Tags: practical-islam, zakat, loan, debt

I have paid a deposit to buy a home and an agreement of sales and purchase has been signed. But the full amount is to be paid next month and I'm calculating my zakat this month.

**Question:** Can a future debt that is already contracted to be in effect as of next month be deducted from the zakat money that is due this months?

Comment: please refer to http://www.hidaya.org/publications/zakat-information/who-is-required-to-pay-zakat